# Bash - Number color based on sign, tabbed

Tags: awk, colors, terminal, printf, tabular

I have lines like these in the terminal

```
8  XLM      3.85  -10.18  -32.94   0.00003836      0.564      0.470    8.402
9  MIOTA   -0.60   -3.38  -11.22    0.0002438      3.582      2.986    8.300
10 DASH     0.55   -2.01   -6.55    0.0742421   1090.820    909.358    7.102
11 NEO     -0.40   -0.88   27.09   0.00832249    122.280    101.938    6.626
12 TRX      7.33  -18.68   42.45   0.00000791      0.116      0.097    6.369
```

and I would like to print the 3,4,5 fields in green if they're positive or in red if they're negative. I'm using awk and printf but cannot have both color and correct tabbing with printf.

If I add color codes with awk like

```
awk '{ if($3<0){$3="\033[0;31m"sprintf("%.2f",$3)"\033[0;0m"} else {$3="\033[0;32m"sprintf("%.2f",$3)"\033[0;0m"};}1'
```

then the tabbing is lost or messed up.

The full command without colors is

```
curl -s "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR&limit=20" | jq -r '.[] | [.rank, .symbol, .percent_change_1h, .percent_change_24h, .percent_change_7d, .price_btc, .price_usd, .price_eur, .market_cap_eur] | @tsv' | awk '{ $3=sprintf("%.2f",$3); $4=sprintf("%.2f",$4); $5=sprintf("%.2f",$5); $6=sprintf("%.8f",$6); $7=sprintf("%.2f",$7); $8=sprintf("%.2f",$8); $9=sprintf("%.3f",$9/(1*10^9)) }1' | xargs printf '%2s %-5s %7s %7s %7s %12s %10s %10s %8s\n' 'r' 'curr' '1d' '24h' '7d' 'btc' 'usd' 'eur' 'mcap B'
```

Comment: pipe the result into `column -t` ?

Comment: I tried that but I can't control the cell alignment and it's not as readable as with printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field spacing is getting modified because you're modifying a field which causes awk to recompile the record replacing input spaces (IFS) with OFS values. If you change the whole record instead of any individual field then awk won't change the spacing between fields:

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { red="\033[0;31m"; green="\033[0;32m"; norm="\033[0;0m" }
{
    for (i=3; i<=5; i++) {
        $0 = gensub("(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"i-1"})([^[:space:]]+)", "\\1" ($i < 0 ? red : green) "\\3" norm,1)
    }
    print
}
```

or with any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { red="\033[0;31m"; green="\033[0;32m"; norm="\033[0;0m" }
{
    for (i=3; i<=5; i++) {
        sub("([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"i-1"}", "&" ($i < 0 ? red : green))
        sub("([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"i-1"}[^[:space:]]+", "&" norm)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
8  XLM      3.85  -10.18  -32.94   0.00003836      0.564      0.470    8.402
9  MIOTA   -0.60   -3.38  -11.22    0.0002438      3.582      2.986    8.300
10 DASH     0.55   -2.01   -6.55    0.0742421   1090.820    909.358    7.102
11 NEO     -0.40   -0.88   27.09   0.00832249    122.280    101.938    6.626
12 TRX      7.33  -18.68   42.45   0.00000791      0.116      0.097    6.369
```

and so you can see the colors:

[image]

Comment:  thanks a lot! I'm a bit lost on the regexp. You're wrapping the i-th field with a color char and a no color char, I suppose. But I don't get how it works. Why double square brackets and what is i-1 matching? Is it some awk custom regexp to match the i-th field or it would work in general? 

Comment: `[:space:]` is a character class. `[[:soace:]]` is a bracket expression containing the character class `[:space:]`. Google those terms. `[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+` is a series of non-spaces followed by a series of spaces. `([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}` is 2 repetitions of the non-spaces-followed-by-spaces (i.e matches the first 2 fields+spaces of each input line). `i` is the current field number 3, 4, or 5. `i-1` is 1 less than that number so when i=3 `"([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){"i-1"}"` matches up to right before field 3. You asked "would work in general" - depends what "in general" means

Comment: thanks again, it's clear now :) with "in general" I meant if the {i-1} was an awk specific regexp syntax or not, but after reading your explanation I think it is not awk specific.